# Boost async_write callback as a member function of another class instance

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a protocol structure where one class takes care of protocol states (`Protocol`) and another class takes care of send and receiving messages (`Comm`).
I´m using `boost:asio` in asynchronous mode.

So I have the following code structure:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include "boost/bind.hpp"

class Comm {
public:
    Comm::Comm();
    void SendMessage(std::string message, void (callback) (const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, std::size_t bytesTranferred));

private:
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> mySocket;
};

Comm::Comm()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("192.168.0.1");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    mySocket->connect(*iterator);
}
void Comm::SendMessage(std::string message, void (callback) (const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, std::size_t bytesTranferred))
{
    mySocket->async_send(boost::asio::buffer(message.c_str(), message.length()), boost::bind(&callback)); // <<< ERROR HERE

}

class Protocol {

public: 
    void SendMessage(std::string message); 
    void SendMessageHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, std::size_t bytesTranferred);

private:
    Comm channel;
};

void Protocol::SendMessage(std::string message)
{
    channel.SendMessage(message, &SendMessageHandler); // <<< ERROR HERE 
}

void Protocol::SendMessageHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, std::size_t bytesTranferred)
{
    if (!errorCode)
        std::cout << "Send OK" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Send FAIL." << std::endl;
}
```

As shown, I need that the callback of the `async_send` to be a non-static function of the caller´s class, so I have to pass the callback function in `SendMessage` and use it as a parameter in `async_send`.

These both statements are not compiling. I´ve tried variations but I can´t find what what´s going on here.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this using [binding to class method](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_pointers_to_memb):

```
void Comm::SendMessage(std::string message, boost::function< void(const boost::system::error_code& , std::size_t) > callback )
{
    mySocket->async_send(boost::asio::buffer(message.c_str(), message.length()), callback);
}
...//later
channel.SendMessage(message, boost::bind(&Protocol::SendMessageHandler, this) );
```

Note/more importantly you have amount unfixable bugs here:

- You are taking `std::string message` by value several times - it will copy the content.
- `Comm::SendMessage` uses local `message` object, which will be destroyed **before** async operation will complete (`boost::asio::buffer` will not copy content).
- It will be hard to use 2 or more `Comm` objects, since each have its own `ioService` (you will not able to run them all at same time)
- No shared_ptr or any other capability to control object lifetime: your `SendMessageHandler` can be called when `Protocol` already destroyed.
- `Protocol` does not control write parallelism, and multiple `SendMessage` calls can lead to write mixed buffers into sockets, this can/will send complete trash over network.
- More fatal/minor issues, no point to search for them.

Consider taking one of the [asio examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html) as base usage pattern.

Comment: PSIAlt, you've pointed out interesting things that needs to be treated for sure, but the suggested code does not solve the original question: How to call a non-static method of another class. When trying to compile the code with your suggestions I'm getting the `error C2825: 'F': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'` error...

Comment: In fact I cannot understand basic studd - the `boost::bind(&Protocol::SendMessageHandler, this)` usage... What does the `this` means here ?

Comment: @Mendes its a way to bind non-static class member to boost::bind. **this** in this case is a pointer to current class instance (a `Protocol*`). Added manual link to the answer

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Is compiling fine, but it's crashing inside the `async_send`. Calling the `callback` function alone works (`std::size_t test; boost::system::error_code ec; stdcallback(ec, test);` instead of calling the `async_send`...